# How to set Navbar to be a sidebar by default?

Tags: 7

[Drupal 7's Navbar module](https://www.drupal.org/project/navbar) is:

- **In wide windows**, a bar across the top, with no dropdowns, just links to main sections like Content, Structure etc
- **In medium-width and narrow windows**, a sidebar or dropdown menu, with accordion-style dropdowns allowing primary menu items to be expanded and secondary menu items shown without leaving the page.

I want to give users the sidebar view, even on wide screen devices, so they can use the secondary menu dropdowns it offers.

I want it to look like this when the menu is chosen, even in wide devices, similar to the old Admin module:

[image]

I can't find any way to do this within Navbar. What's the simplest way to do this, with minimal hacking to the Navbar module or hard-coded overrides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this in a very simple custom module **without any hacking or patching to Navbar code**.

Just create and enable a custom module that contains (assuming your module is called `custom`):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_navbar_breakpoints_alter().
 *
 * Nullifies the breakpoint that switches the navbar to horizontal orientation
 */

function custom_navbar_breakpoints_alter( &$data ) {
    $data["wide"] = "not all";  
}
```

The navbar module defines a hook, `hook_navbar_breakpoints_alter`, using `drupal_alter`, that allows its hard-coded breakpoints to be overwritten.

`not all` seems to me the cleanest and most intuitive way to implement an impossible media query condition (related: [How to set a media query condition that is never met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065007/how-to-set-a-media-query-condition-that-is-never-met)).

This makes the switchable horizontal masthead view of the navbar menu, quite literally, the default on not any device.

Answer (score 1):

With the navbar in horizontal format as on your widescreen devices, click this button in the top right corner of the window:

[image]

This will make the navbar show vertical, until the time when the user clicks the button at the end of the vertical sidebar to reverse this.

It's not by default vertical for widescreen devices with that, though. It still needs a user action to make it vertical.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is having the navbar showing *by default* as vertical for any screen size, you can follow the suggestion [presented here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2410825#comment-9535631):

`if(localStorage){
   localStorage.setItem('Drupal.navbar.trayVerticalLocked',true);
}`

on

```
navbar/js/navbar.js
```

If you prefer, just grab [this commit I made](https://github.com/edgeryders/edgeryders-commons/commit/4f9dcfc8a1fceda68d412f311b79cfb73cbd2315).